# generate an image from a vector, can't display the image

Tags: matlab

i have an image descriptor in a file.modQDH i need to display this image

this is my code

```
imagefiles = dir('*.modQDH');      
nfiles = length(imagefiles);    % Number of files found

fprintf('number est ');
fprintf('%d ',nfiles );
 fprintf('%n');


A = importdata('obj1__0.modQDH');
disp(A);
```

when i use disp(a) the result is my vetcor

but me i need the image corresponding to this vector

i have used image(A) and imshow (A) but it doesn't works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

disp shows the value of a variable, it does not create an image rendering

see 
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/disp.html

try using imagesc which attempts to take care of some of the scaling issues